# Other hardware for camera slots?

Tags: gpio, serial, led

I think the raspberry should get more cool hardware like the camera that works with the slot onboard. I'd love to get a fast RS485 onto this slot because i need all my GPIOs for LEDs. Currently I use 2 raspberries, one to recieve data from RS485 over a RaspiComm and a second one which outputs data to LEDs over GPIO. There raspberries are connected via LAN. Is there a way to do this only with one raspberry? I mean receiving data and setting some LEDs blinking?

Comment: Have you considered using some port expanders (based on I²C, for example) to free some GPIOs?

Comment: No, i wanted to use the port that gets used for the camera. http://content.hwigroup.net/images/news/raspberry_pi_camera_02.jpg

Comment: @danbru1211, Welcome to StackExchange and thanks for your contribution. For an easy badge, read the "About" article near the search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The camera port is not a general purpose port. It is connected to the GPU directly and uses either CCP2 or CSI-2 (camera specific protocols) to communicate with the camera.

Have you looked at the [P5 header](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#P5_header) that was added on the Rev 2 boards?  It makes 4 additional GPIO ports available.

Comment: Since, as you said, camera port is connected to GPU, ARM CPU has no access to this port. This means that everything that communicates on this port has to be written in the GPU firmware. There is no access for GPU programming for people outside of Broadcom, however.

Comment: Not only that, the protocols are not open.  You must pay to get access to them.