# Creating an HDMI Pass-Through Connection

Tags: video, hdmi, output, input-device

I would be very interested to know if anyone on here might be able to provide some insights into the feasibility and/or proper approach to add a HDMI input to the Raspberry Pi in an effort to allow the raspberry pi to consume content from this port. For example... would it be feasible to convert the HDMI signal from a device through a USB cable (input into the raspberry pi?).... Or, is it technically feasible to convert the existing HDMI "output port" on the Pi to an HDMI input port??

As a follow-up question on this, does anyone have any experience in creating a pass-through connection for HDMI content for the Pi?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, no you can't do this with a Raspberry Pi.

The long answer is, perhaps with enough external hardware and a great deal of knowledge of how HDMI works you might be able to do something like you describe.

If you want to see and example of a hackable ARM device running linux that can do HDMI manipulation and pass through you can look at the [NeTV board](http://www.sutajiokousagi.com/w/index.php?title=NeTV_Main_Page) as an example. It uses an FPGA to handle the HDMI stuff though.

Comment: does your answer include the consideration of the camera input?

Comment: See [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8486/877). The camera port uses a different protocol that is not related to HDMI.

Comment: thanks... final follow up... does any external USB exist to this extent?

Answer (score 2):

**HDMI Input on Raspberry PI**

The PZ-HDMI from e-mediavision.com will allow you to capture HDMI video and audio into the Raspberry Pi, you can use OMX Player to display the captured video through the Pi's HDMI output port as well.

The PZ-HDSDI allows SDI video to be captured on the raspberry Pi.

[e-mediavision.com](http://www.e-mediavision.com)

Answer (score 1):

A new driver for [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/2016/10/25/a-new-driver-is-born/) has been released recently which allows to create a capture device compliant with the Video4Linux2 standard from HDMI output. This should answer the second part of your question.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that for a RasberryPi this effectively has the ability of turning the HDMI output port on the board into a HDMI "Input" port??

Comment: read through the description of this demo on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wthS8TPk2DE&feature=youtu.be . The DEMO is *one example* of use of the uv4l-raspidisp driver which can be used for more generic stuff

Comment: No its just showing that you can obtain a stream of the HDMI output and do whatever (such as display it in a webpage). Very very cool. Not input though.

Answer (score 1):

Well [B101 by Auvidea](https://auvidea.com/b101-hdmi-to-csi-2-bridge-15-pin-fpc/) can become an HDMI input for a Raspberry Pi.

It works as a Raspberry camera, but it takes a signal from HDMI in. It uses a Toshiba chip. You can have a live view, take stills and record a video. I guess it fits your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can now (2022) buy very cheap hdmi--> usb video capture devices. I bought one and it worked with a RaspberryPi (plugging the usb output from the capture device to the Rpi) and in terminal typed 'cheese' --> it worked.

You can write a 20 second file with command
ffmpeg  -i /dev/video0   -t 0:0:20  ./X.mp4